# Cache Configuration for MIPS Processor

Tags: caching, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

I am having trouble figuring out the tag, set, and byte offset fields for a 32-bit MIPS processor with the following cache configurations:

(a) A direct mapped cache with capacity 8192 bytes and block size 32 bytes.
(b) A 8-way set associate cache with capacity 2048 bytes and block size 16 bytes.

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on this matter. Thank you!

I attempted to use the formula for calculating the number of bits for each field in a cache memory address:

`Tag = 32 - (log2(cache capacity/block size) + log2(block size))

Set/Index = log2(cache capacity/block size)

Byte offset = log2(block size)`

I expected to be able to use this formula to find the number of bits for each field, but I am unsure if this is the correct formula for this specific MIPS processor.

As a result, I am seeking assistance to verify my understanding and solution.

Comment: You don't mention which specific MIPS processor other than 32-bit, but there's nothing MIPS specific about the problem statement and cache configurations.

Comment: Your formulas are correct for scenario (a), but do not account for multiple ways as for problem (b), which will require you to use the 8 as in number of ways.